# Getting NaN in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to push contents of One array into another array but when I console log the new array I get the contents of the old array in the new array with NaN appended to it.

I have tried declaring my array using [] and new Array() but I am still getting the same output

```
this.active_bid = data[0].active_bids; //Length of 3

var timer_act = new Array(this.active_bid.length)
for(var i=0; i< this.active_bid.length; i++){
    timer_act[i] = (Number(this.active_bid[i].time_left));
}
console.log(timer_act)
```

outputs

```
[0,0,0, NaN]
```

The first three zeroes are valid but I don't understand why I am getting NaN

Comment: console this.active_bid[i].time_left which seems to be undefined or string

Comment: what's the output if you omit `Number` .... or better still, what's the output of `console.log(this.active_bid.slice())`

Comment: There is actually no need to put Number wrapping

Comment: The reason you would use `Number(value)` is to check if `value` can be converted to a number and perform a type conversion, otherwise it returns `NaN`.  `data[0].active_bids` must not have a length of 3, if you're getting an output of length 4...

Comment: You say the array has a length of 3 but your output is showing 4 entries. Either your expectations about the `active_bids` array are wrong or there's some other code (not shown) pushing `NaN` into your `timer_act` array. You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57263080/edit) and show **exactly** what's  in `data[0].active_bids`

Comment: That is impossible with the code you've given;  You should provide a codesandbox demo showcasing the issue with demo data.  The data you've given in the comment above isn't an array... and thus can't `.length` it

Comment: what's the output if you omit `Number` .... or better still, what's the output of `console.log(this.active_bid.slice())` - please add this information to the question

Comment: `where i have listed the properties` - of a SINGLE item? so how do you even expect THREE values in the output if you only have ONE in the input?

Comment: Please execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(data[0].active_bids))`, copy the result from your console and add it to your question (by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57263080/edit)). I also suggest trying `console.log(JSON.stringify(timer_act))` instead of `console.log(timer_act)`. See if the results are any different

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have an issue with your `data[0].active_bids` input, it *does* contain an extra object without a `time_left` field defined, hence the mysterious `NaN` value.

```js
this.active_bid = [{"time_left": 0},{"time_left": 1},{"time_left": 2},{}];
var timer_act = new Array(this.active_bid.length)
for (var i = 0; i < this.active_bid.length; i++) {
  timer_act[i] = (Number(this.active_bid[i].time_left));
}
console.log(timer_act)
```

If you filter out any such results via [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
this.active_bid = [{"time_left": 0},{"time_left": 1},{"time_left": 2},{}];
var timer_act = this.active_bid
           .map(obj => obj.time_left)
           .filter(obj => obj !== undefined);
console.log(timer_act)
```